# Design a sequence detector that detects when the sequence “10”

Tags: digital-logic

Design a sequence detector that detects when the sequence “10” occurs in a stream of input (single bit input). Upon detecting “10”, the detector will produce an output of “0”, else output will be “1”.
Design the sequence detector using BOTH Mealy and Moore model. For each model design, provide:
i. State Diagram 
ii. State Table
iii. The output and the FFs’ input expressions

what is meant by single bit input? i have tried to find out how to do it but most example are using 1011 or 110 but not '10'.

Comment: Single bit input means serial bit sequence.

Answer (score 2):

A single bit is one bit of a bit sequence.

Your examples with 1011 and 110 are bit streams, each made up of a number of bits.

For example, the sequence 1011 is made up of 4 single bits.  They are most probably meant to be input right-most first (least-significant bit, or LSB, first), so the bit sequence would be:

```
In
1
1
0
1
```

For that sequence as each bit is input, your Mealy machine design would be expected to output:

```
In Out
1  1
1  1
0  1
1  0
```

since it would be remembering the previous state from the last bit it saw.  Remember - Mealy machines are FSMs, so an input value would change a state, and the output depends on input value and current state.

For the Moore machine, since the output is determined solely by the current state, the inputs would have to trigger different state changes to form the output value rather than just having the one state for the previous bit's value.

Now grab your pen and paper and draw the machines that would produce that output.

Comment: thanks for the guides. 
but i'm still blur in this topic. i hope u can help me further.

so in detecting sequence "10", once "10" have been detected, it will go back to the initial? since '0' is not the next pattern?

Comment: Yes. You are always working in effect with 2 bits. The current bit, and the previous bit.  So if you have 110101110 coming in LSB first, you would be looking at 0,1, then 1,1 then 1,1, then 1,0 then 0,1 then 1,0 then 0,1, etc. Easier to see each bit as a different number or letter. If you have the bits DCBA then you are examining ?A, AB, BC, CD and D? where ? is whatever comes before (initial state), or comes after that snippet.